Train a network to find the most sharp image from a group of images
I'm new to deep learning, and I am trying to find a solution to the below scenario, any suggestions about the keywords would be greatly appreciated.
I have a data set with groups of images. In each group, the content of images look very similar to each other, the only difference is their sharpness. The images with best sharpness have labels of "good". The images with slight blurriness have labels of "acceptable". And blurred images have labels of "blur".
So each group have images with these 3 labels.
The model suppose to work as this: input a group of images, the model will figure out the one with best sharpness and label it as "good". Then compare other images in the same group with the best one, and label them as "good", "acceptable" or "blur".
I assume it's kind of image classification, but the tricky part is that the sharpness is different in different groups. So an image labeled as "blur" in one group may have the same visual effects as an image labeled as "good" in another group. The key point is to find the most sharp image within one group, even if it's still blurred when seeing with human eyes.
Thank you so much for any suggestions.
